# Tracking all code usage in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have been tasked with taking an existing asp.net website that has many lines of code and projects and redesigning it. I would like to identify the code used the most so that I can know what I should carry over to the redesign, and what code is not used at all and can potentially be removed completely.

How could I track every method/property that gets called when users are on the site?

There are both vb.net and C# projects in the solution, so each language would have to be supported. Also, free/OSS solutions are the best for me right now.

I am currently using VS.NET 2015 Community.

Comment: If you are talking about finding which bits of your sites real users are or aren't using then you probably want to use something like Google Analytics which will track page views and lots of other things which will give you a detailed pattern of usage and traffic.

Comment: JetBrains dotTrace is probably one of the best tools for profiling performance in .NET applications including ASP.NET. You could download their 10 day full feature trial here https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler This should give you a clear indication at a code level, how the application works and where you could best improve it

Comment: Although you may find tools to track what's commonly used/not used, It seems like this would be better approached from an 'expected functionality' standpoint.  What do the users of the website or your management expect the site to do in terms of tasks, updating/inserting into the database etc.  If you have an idea of the different workflow of your users, and can understand what parts of the existing site they use, you can make a much more educated guess than just deleting functionality that a 3rd party tool tells you is not used.

Comment: Speak to your users. The only sure way to find out what is used and what is not. After that look on your analytics and data. There is no clear cut answer to this question - it all depends!

Comment: @trailmax While I agree it's good to speak to the users, you absolutely cannot rely on them to tell you the full truth!

Comment: @DavidG oh, absolutely! That's why you need to look on data and analytics as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways:

1. Introduce some method level tracing by using some AOP framework (like PostSharp). In this case, you can log the method call chain of one specific request. Then you can start from there.
2. If your app backed with SQL Server, enable profiling and look through all SQL queries executed from one request. Then you look back to codebase and refactor them.
3. Use CodeMap to understand code base and do it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use ReSharper. Right click the project and select 'Find Code Issues'. You will see 'Unused Symbols' to show which components are not being used.

Comment: This will only give you code that is not accessable, OP is looking to find code/features that are never used.